# Exit loop coding style

Tags: c#, java, coding-style

I've got a coding style question. Below are two looping functions that do the same thing but with a slightly different loop exit technique. I just wanted to get a sense of what you guys prefer.

I personally prefer the first. I don't see why I should declare a new variable and break a loop when I know there's nothing else to be done.

```
private SomeObj getSomeObj(ArrayList<SomeObj> items, String type)
{
    for (SomeObj someObj : items) {
        if ( someObj.getField().equals(type) ) {
            return someObj;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


private SomeObj getSomeObj(ArrayList<SomeObj> items, String type)
{
    SomeObj found = null
    for (SomeObj someObj : items) {
        if ( someObj.getField().equals(type) ) {
            found = someObj;
                    break;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: This kind of question is not welcome in stackoverflow, you should probably ask it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should not ask discussion type questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Both have different purposes. They are not replacements for each other.

First one comes out from the method

Second one comes out from the loop NOT method.

Let us say if there is some code which manipulates SomeObj after the for loop, then results will differ from first method to second method.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches could not replace each other in every situation. Suppose you want to execute the code after loop finishes then return could not do that for you and vice versa. In your case both could be used but not in every situation.

*Statements after for loop, which you do not want to execute get executed with break*

```
private SomeObj getSomeObj(ArrayList<SomeObj> items, String type)
{
    SomeObj found = null
    for (SomeObj someObj : items) {
        if ( someObj.getField().equals(type) ) {
            found = someObj;
                    break;
        }
    }
    //Statements you do not want to execute get executed with break  

    return found;
}
```

*Statements after for loop, which you want to execute do not get executed with return*

```
private SomeObj getSomeObj(ArrayList<SomeObj> items, String type)
{
    SomeObj found = null
    for (SomeObj someObj : items) {
        if ( someObj.getField().equals(type) ) {
            found = someObj;
                    return;
        }
    }
    //Statements you want to execute do not get executed with return

    return found;
}
```

Comment: you could claim lots of different possible scenarios, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Please stop emplacing random chunks of your prose in code blocks!!

Comment: Are you asking for the comments in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first.  In general, i prefer early exits from methods as it tends to reduce nesting.